# Como usando actionBar aparecer ícone + texto dos itens?

Tags: android, android-layout

Eu declarei no Manifest android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" para a actionBar e defini os itens como showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" aparecer na parte de baixo da tela, segue a figura abaixo:

[image: ActionBar]
Mesmo tendo espaço a actionBar não mostra icone + texto, ela só mostra os icones.
Gostaria que aparecesse igual nessa imagem só que na parte de baixo:
[image: ActionBar]

Comment: Está usando a biblioteca `AppCompat` para o `ActionBar`?

Comment: não nem sei o que essa biblioteca faz

Comment: android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" serve pra com que a actionbar apareça na parte de baixo so que mesmo tendo espaco pra aparecer icone + texto nao aparece, só o icone...

Comment: a essa biblioteca aew e de suporte ne... agora me lembrei acho

Comment: Isso, mas como está usando o `ActionBar` nativo, não é necessário usa-lá.

Comment: hum.. o estranho q todos os exemplos q vi na net pra fazer aparecer usa android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" e em  todos os casos somente aparece os icones... eu queria saber uma forma de forçar aparecer

Comment: Já passei por isso. O que fiz para resolver isso foi criar um custon ActionBar e usar o setCustomView para sobrepor o ActionBar default.

Comment: @Borachio mas vao ficar 2 actionbar? uma sobreposta e a default que nao aparece ou vai substituir a default?

Comment: @Borachio de qualquer modo se você desejar expor como fazer essa custom actiobar agradeço muito.

Comment: Acho que algo em paralelo ao que o @Borachio citou, seria usar um `actionLayout` para o ícone do menu. Em vez de setar apenas um `Drawable`, com o `actionLayout` você pode setar um layout xml para cada item (podendo ser o mesmo, configurando na criação do menu), incluindo qualquer `View`.

Comment: vou ver como faz isso.. vlw pela dica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução que vou detalhar faz uso do `ActionLayout` do `MenuItem`, que está disponível tanto a partir do *Android* 11+, quanto nas versões anteriores, mas com o uso da biblioteca de suporte v7 `AppCompat`. Logo a solução poderá ser aplicada em todos os dispositivos.

## Configuração da `Activity` no AndroidManifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".app.activity.MenuActivity"
    android:label="Exemplo Menu"
    android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
/>
```

Como você citou, é preciso definir o `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` para que o `SplitActionBar` apareça.

## Menu (`menu_activity.xml`)

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ed_save1"
        android:title="@string/action_save"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_save_dark"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/menu_item_layout"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_item_layout"
        android:showAsAction="withText|ifRoom"
        app:showAsAction="withText|ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/ed_save2"
        android:title="@string/action_save"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_save_dark"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/menu_item_layout"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_item_layout"
        android:showAsAction="withText|ifRoom"
        app:showAsAction="withText|ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/ed_save3"
        android:title="@string/action_save"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_save_dark"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/menu_item_layout"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_item_layout"
        android:showAsAction="withText|ifRoom"
        app:showAsAction="withText|ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/ed_save4"
        android:title="@string/action_save"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_save_dark"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/menu_item_layout"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_item_layout"
        android:showAsAction="withText|ifRoom"
        app:showAsAction="withText|ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Nele vemos alguns atributos repetidos, com o schema `app` e o schema `android`. Faço isso porque os atributos com schema `app` são para o `AppCompat` e os com schema `android` para o `ActionBar` nativo. Se não utilizar o `AppCompat` pode remover sem problemas.

## Definição do `menu_item_layout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:paddingTop="4dip"
    android:paddingBottom="4dip"
    android:paddingLeft="8dip"
    android:paddingRight="8dip"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="6pt"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    style="?attr/actionButtonStyle" />
```

Layout comum, apenas um `TextView`, onde iremos configurar o ícone e o texto. Se quiser pode customizar conforme a necessidade.

## MenuActivity

```
/**
 * Created by wakim on 28/09/14.
 */
public class MenuActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity, menu);

        for(int i = 0, c = menu.size(); i < c; ++i) {
            MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);

            // A linha abaixo é para quem usa o AppCompat.
            //TextView actionLayout = (TextView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

            // Recuperando a View que representa o Menu
            TextView actionLayout = (TextView) item.getActionView();

            // Atribuo o text baseado no title do Menu
            actionLayout.setText(item.getTitle());

            // Atribuo o drawable de acordo com o ícone.
            // Estou usando o drawableTop, mas poderá usar qualquer um dos:
            // drawableLeft, drawableTop, drawableRight, drawableBottom
            actionLayout.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, item.getIcon(), null, null);

            // Somos obrigados a configurar manualmente o OnClickListener
            // Ja que estamos configurando uma View Customizada para o Menu 
            actionLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.ed_save1:
                // Tratamento para click no item ed_save1
            break;
            case R.id.ed_save2:
                // Tratamento para click no item ed_save2
            break;
            case R.id.ed_save3:
                // Tratamento para click no item ed_save3
            break;
            case R.id.ed_save4:
                // Tratamento para click no item ed_save4
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Minha `Activity` herda de `ActionBarActivity` porque estou usando  o `AppCompat`, que me obriga a herda-lá para ter acesso ao `ActionBar`. Caso esteja usando apenas o `ActionBar` nativo, poderá herdar de `Activity` sem nenhum problema.

## Resultado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

## Edit

No caso do menu construído no `ActionMode`, é preciso adaptar a solução para armazenar o estado do `ActionMode` e usá-lo para recuperar o `Menu` criado e respectivamente o `MenuItem` clicado. Assim chamando o método `onActionItemClicked`, mantendo a mesma lógica.

## MenuActivity

```
    /**
 * Created by wakim on 28/09/14.
 */
public class MenuActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener, ActionMode.Callback {

    ActionMode mActionMode;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        startActionMode(this);

        // Se estiver usando a biblioteca AppCompat, para iniciar o ActionMode
        // é preciso chamar o método abaixo, em vez do método acima.
        //startSupportActionMode(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // O menu será criado no ActionMode...
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /***
        Método que configura o ActionLayout do menu,
        com os atributos do próprio MenuItem
    */
    void configureActionLayout(Menu menu) {
        for(int i = 0, c = menu.size(); i < c; ++i) {
            MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
            TextView actionLayout = (TextView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
            //TextView actionLayout = (TextView) item.getActionView();

            actionLayout.setText(item.getTitle());
            actionLayout.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, item.getIcon(), null, null);

            actionLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Tenta fazer o tratamento caso seja um MenuItem de um menu criado no ActionMode
        if(handleActionModeIfPossible(v.getId())) {
            return;
        }

        // Tratamento padrão, caso não seja um MenuItem do ActionMode
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.ed_save1:
                // Tratamento para click no menu
                Log.i("tag", "ed_save1");
                break;
            case R.id.ed_save2:
                // Tratamento para click no menu
                Log.i("tag", "ed_save2");
                break;
            case R.id.ed_save3:
                // Tratamento para click no menu
                Log.i("tag", "ed_save3");
                break;
            case R.id.ed_save4:
                // Tratamento para click no menu
                Log.i("tag", "ed_save4");
                break;
        }
    }

    boolean handleActionModeIfPossible(int menuId) {

        // Se nao temos um ActionMode no momento podemos parar 
        if(mActionMode == null) {
            return false;
        }

        // Recupero o possível MenuItem do Menu atual do ActionMode
        MenuItem menuItem = mActionMode.getMenu().findItem(menuId);

        // Se nao existe um MenuItem com id "menuId", não podemos continuar.
        if(menuItem == null) {
            return false;
        }

        onActionItemClicked(mActionMode, menuItem);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.am_menu_activity, menu);
        configureActionLayout(menu);

        mActionMode = mode;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        mActionMode = mode;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        mActionMode = mode;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        mActionMode = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: muito bom.. minha duvida seria na questão na utilização desse menu customizado pelo action mode que quando eu clico em algum item da view ele chama o método onActionItemClicked(), mas quando clico ele chama onclick() pois esta setado la em cima actionLayout.setOnClickListener(this);.. eu queria saber uma forma de setar para chamar o método de clique do action mode onActionItemClicked()

Comment: para criar o menu eu não estou utilizando o método  onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu), mas sim o método onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)

Comment: Bem legal essa observação, como não citou isso na pergunta fui pelo caminho mais comum. Vou incluir em minha resposta uma adaptação para contemplar esse caso, só um tempo para preparar o código em meu dispositivo.

Comment: muito obrigado.. foi mal da minha parte, pois pensei que a solução seria pra qualquer caso.. não tinha imaginado que precisaria setar uma ação para o clique, somente criar um layout para o menu.

Comment: @PedroRangel, espero que não tenha interpretado meu comentário como ironia, não era o propósito. Foi bom ter citado, porque deixa uma resposta mais abrangente, e de fato não iria funcionar sem o tratamento adequado. Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: de modo algum interpretei com ironia você foi correto no seu comentário^^ deu tudo certo muito obrigado de verdade.. só perturbando mais um pouco você^^ com relação ao posicionamento dos item pelo método actionLayout.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds no top se o texto abaixo do item não aparece direito tenho que usar a biblioteca de suporte, AppCompat?

Comment: Não precisa não, se o texto não apareceu é porque não esta tendo espaço suficiente. Tente mudar a posição do `Drawable` para uma posição horizontal ou diminua o tamanho do ícone ou texto. O `ActionBar` tem uma altura fixa, se o `TextView` ficar muito alto, ele vai cortar.

Comment: hum.. blz muito obrigado novamente.